# React hook form with customize controller

Tags: react-select, react-hook-form

```
 <Controller
            name={'productType'}
            control={props.control}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => {
                   return (
                      <SelectInput
                                 options={productTypeOption}
                                 label={'Product Type'}
                                 isDisabled={isDisabled.productTypeDisable}
                                 onChange={onProductTypeChange}
                                 isLoading={isLoading.productType}
                                 statusMsg={productTypeOption.length}
                        />
)}}>
</Controller>
```

I got my select input componenet from react-select package and i want to use react hook form controller with it btw i already got my own onChange props on it , In docs to send data to useForm i also need to put field onchange on it so how to bring onChange useForm with my own logic???

```
     const onProductTypeChange = (e) => {
          setServiceOtherOption([])
          setServiceQuantitesOption([])
          const valueSelect = e.value
          props.setJobData((arr) => ({
               ...arr,
               productType: valueSelect
          }
          ))
     }
```

this is my on change needed

Answer (score 1):

You can set `onChange` prop on `SelectInput` as a function which calls your `onProductTypeChange` function and also call `onChange` of react-hook-form, like this:

```
<SelectInput
    onChange={(e)=> {
      onProductTypeChange(e);
      onChange(e.value);
    }}
   ...
/>
```